# Can't make a multi-variable linear regression converge

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

The following is a simple linear regression/ML code that I have modified. For all initial weight and bias (i.e. weight = np.array([0.03, 0.04, 0.02]), bias = 0.01), the training will blow up (It just won't converge).

Wonder if there is a bug in the code or how to choose good initial values (weight and bias) so it will converge.

```
#Adopted from http://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linear_regression.html
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt


def predict(X, weight, bias):
    return np.dot(X, weight) + bias

def cost_function(X, Y, weight, bias):
    companies = X.shape[0]
    return np.sum((predict(X, weight, bias) - Y) **2) / companies



def update_weights(X, Y, weight, bias, learning_rate):
    companies = X.shape[0]

    dW = 2 * np.dot(X.T,  predict(X, weight, bias) - Y)
    db = 2 * np.sum(predict(X, weight, bias) - Y)
    """
    for i in range(companies):
        # Calculate partial derivatives
        # -2x(y - (mx + b))
        dw += -2*X[i] * (sales[i] - (weight*X[i] + bias))

        # -2(y - (mx + b))
        db += -2*(sales[i] - (weight*X[i] + bias))
    """
    #print(dW, db)
    # We subtract because the derivatives point in direction of steepest ascent
    #weight -= (dW / companies) * learning_rate
    #bias -= (db / companies) * learning_rate

    return weight - (dW / companies) * learning_rate, bias - (db / companies) * learning_rate

def train(X, Y, weight, bias, learning_rate, iters):
    cost_history = []

    for i in range(iters):
        weight,bias = update_weights(X, Y, weight, bias, learning_rate)

        #Calculate cost for auditing purposes
        cost = cost_function(X, Y, weight, bias)
        cost_history.append(cost)

        # Log Progress
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print ("iter: "+str(i) + " cost: "+str(cost) + "\n")

    return weight, bias, cost_history

#the Advertising.csv is from http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_data = genfromtxt('Advertising.csv', delimiter=',')
    X = my_data[1:, 1:4:1]
    Y = my_data[1:, 4];  #the sales
    a,b, _ = train(X, Y, np.array([0.03, 0.04, 0.02]), 0.01, 0.001, 1000)
```

The problem is, whatever value I use as initial weight and bias (i.e. weight = np.array([0.03, 0.04, 0.02]), bias = 0.01) will cause the value to blow up.
It just won't converge.
train(X, Y, weight, bias, 0.001, 1000)

**UPDATE1**

When I ran the above code snippet, I got

```
$ python linearRegression_multi.py 
iter: 0 cost: 212337.75728564826

/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:32: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce
  return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
linearRegression_multi.py:11: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum((predict(X, weight, bias) - Y) **2) / companies
iter: 100 cost: inf

linearRegression_multi.py:34: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  return weight - dW * learning_rate / companies , bias - db * learning_rate / companies
iter: 200 cost: nan

iter: 300 cost: nan

iter: 400 cost: nan

iter: 500 cost: nan

iter: 600 cost: nan

iter: 700 cost: nan

iter: 800 cost: nan

iter: 900 cost: nan
```

Comment: Suggestion (I haven't checked the algorithm): Since you have a learning rate, why do dW/companies*learning_rate? Just do: dW * learning rate. Did you normalize the inputs?

Comment: Are you missing the column selector here `X = my_data[1:, ]`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo `X = my_data[1:, ]`, I modified it to `X = my_data[1:, 1:4:1]`, which represent the 3 feature columns.  I moved `*learning_rate` to be after `dW`, but it doesn't seem to help.   Any ideas?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was incorrect.  I tested your code again and it worked fine on a sample data set I generated.  I think it just appears to be 'blowing up' because **dw** and **db** are being printed without first normalizing them by dividing by **companies**.  This displays really large values, since it's a cumulative derivation.  But checking the values returned after training gave the correct values.

Comment: Thanks @LazyElephant for giving it a try. Could you share the sample data that cause it to work? Granted I didn't divid the `dW`, `db` by `companies`, but I should have caused the numbers to blow up since `companies` is only about 200.

Comment: **X**: `np.random.randn(100, 3)` **y** `np.dot(x, np.array([10, 5, 3]) + 9`  The values I used for w and b I just picked randomly.  Then I copied your training statement exactly.

Comment: It resulted in a final value in **a** which was very close to the weight array I used to generate **y**

Comment: If you edit your post with some of the results you're getting, it might help clarify the problem

Comment: @LazyElephant, I tried your values of w and b as `np.array([10, 5, 3])` and `9` and the value blow up.  Note that my `X`, `Y` are from a dataset from internet, not the generated values.  Very frustrated that I can't get it to converge.

Comment: Are the data values very large? Have you tried normalizing them first?

Comment: Also, what's the dataset you're using? Is it the advertising.csv from the website?

Comment: @LazyElephant, you have a good point, it's probably better to normalize the dataset first.  The dataset is from website (documented in the codesnipet just above the main function).  The X has shape/dimension 200 by 3. Y is 200 by 1.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the cause of the problem! The learning rate in this case `0.001` is too high.

Change it to be `0.00001` works.  i,e, change the last line in original snippet to be the following makes it work.

```
a,b, _ = train(X, Y, np.array([0.03, 0.04, 0.02]), 0.01, 0.00001, 1000)
```

Here is the output:

```
python te.py 
iter: 0 cost: 23.07411798374272

iter: 100 cost: 6.479930413738248

iter: 200 cost: 5.097751463999494

iter: 300 cost: 4.528064099014893

iter: 400 cost: 4.263917598438141

iter: 500 cost: 4.1398851132621655

iter: 600 cost: 4.081383875535448

iter: 700 cost: 4.053584811192947

iter: 800 cost: 4.040172367398533

iter: 900 cost: 4.033501506011401
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out